# Expression with String placeholder in the filter part of JsonPath using karate

Tags: karate, jsonpath

I am trying to filter my response using JSON Path where one of the condition using a value from a variable but I am not able to map variable properly, so my filter not working properly.

Sample response JSON:

```
{
   "response":[
      {
         "id":"1234",
         "confirmationCode":"abcd"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am using the below script where I am using variable 'code':

```
* def Code = 'abcd'
* def value = karate.jsonPath($.response[?(@.confirmationCode == ' + Code +')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs carefully please:

```
* def value = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.response[?(@.confirmationCode=='" + Code + "')]")
```